# javascript no funciona en un base64 ¿por qué?

Tags: javascript, html, base64

Tengo una función en base64 que básicamente hace obtener la ubicación de la persona, pero no me quiere funcionar de niguna manera qué puedo hacer? necesito enviarle esta función a un amigo que no sabe dónde está

```js
/* FUNCIÓN */

var x = document.getElementById("demo");

function getLocation() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
  } else { 
    x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
  }
}

function showPosition(position) {
  x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
  "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
}
```

```html
<!-- ESTE ES EL LINK BASE64

data:text/html;base64,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


-->
```

Comment: Un problema es que esa cadena contiene un documento HTML completo, no solo _"la función"_. ¿Cómo quieres enviar el código y por qué en base64? Por cierto, Javascript no puede ejecutarse dentro de una cadena, primero debes decodificar, probablemente extraer el script y, finalmente, ejecutar `eval()` que no es recomendable.

Answer (score 0):

Como te dijeron, lo que tienes es un documento en base 64, cuyo prefijo le dice al browser cómo interpretarlo. Si alguien navega a

```
 <a href='data:text/html;base64,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'>Detector de geolocalización</a>
```

Efectivamente será como si hubiese cargado un archivo HTML que contiene una etiqueta `<script>` con la función. Esto no servirá para gatillar la solicitud de acceder a la ubicación, dado que en la actualidad esa solicitud sólo puede gatillarse desde una url segura. Esto es, urls con protocolo `https` y no `http`, `file` ni `data`.

Referencia: [Deprecating powerful features on insecure origins](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/Home/chromium-security/deprecating-powerful-features-on-insecure-origins)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]